# How to make chat app featuring with file upload like images, videos or pdf in Flutter

Tags: flutter, chat, file-sharing

I know how to code a chat app with Firebase but have no clue with how to do the file sharing feature in flutter with in the chat screen. I am seeking tutorials to help me learn and understand the same. Also the db is not fixed with Firebase. socket.io is what I was thinking to use with MySQL to save the chat, as socket.io is free.

I am happy to hear what is the best suggested technology on the same in term of solution.

Comment: To simplify real-time chat implementation including content sharing, you could try [QuickBlox Flutter SDK](https://docs.quickblox.com/docs/flutter-quick-start) that supports 1-1 chat, group chat and video calls.

Comment: This is undoubtedly an interesting problem, but as stated this question is far too broad for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

You can integrate image,video and pdf feature with the help you third party storage like firebase storage, aws s3 (simple storage service) etc.

And first you have to upload particular file upload into the storage and after that you will gate a link of that uploaded file and now you have to store that link into the firebase database. and after then you will share videourl in video library and imageurl in networkimage() and pdfurl in pdf library.

Comment: how will i get a preview of the same as a thumbnail ?